# why won't INSERT INTO SELECT work in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, sql-insert

I have two tables in the same DB. Table1 was autogenerated with a csv import, column names are all like: COL 1, COL 2, etc. Table2 is a table I created. In both tables, all fields are VARCHAR NULL nullable, except for a PK AI field in Table2. Table 1 has 18 fields. Table 2 has 21 fields.

I am trying to insert the first 18 fields from table1 into table2. My code looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO table2
(First, Last, Address...) 
SELECT COL 1, COl 2, COl 3
FROM table1;
```

This is not working. I have tried with and without backtics and single quotes on both field lists.
The error message only tells me that the error is on line 3.
What am I missing?

Comment: Also, btw, table1 has no PK. and I am not I am ignoring the PK AI field in table2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,

Having `table1` with Col 1, Col 2, Col 3...

and `table2` with named fields First, Last, Address...

You should follow this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(First, Last, Address...) 
SELECT `COL 1` as First, `COl 2` as Last, `COl 3` as Address
FROM table1;
```

I hope this helped ...